# How to list parent child categories if parent child div is not inside one another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to list `categories and sub categories` but problem is parent categories div is different and child div is different `that is child div is not inside parent div` so i am not getting how to list parent - child categories.

This  is my code:

```
<!-- Parent Div Section  -->
   <div ng-repeat="item in MyData">
                    <table >
                        <tr>
                            <td >{{ item.parentCategoryName }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
   <!-- Child Categories Div Section  -->
 <div>
                    <table >
                        <tr>
                            <td >{{ item.ChildCategoryName }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>
```

**Json Structure:**

```
[
  {
    "parentCategoryName": "Electronics",
    "SubCategories": [
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "Mobile",
      },
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "TV",
      },
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "Ac",
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "parentCategoryName": "Sports",
    "SubCategories": [
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "Shoes",
      },
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "Bike",
      },
      {
        "ChildCategoryName": "Bags",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Note**:Although it seems like both parent child div are same but there are lots of codes which i havent shown for better understanding that is why both div are in different section.So i cant change that because above design will render same output as shown in expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. See the code below

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in MyData">
    <td>{{item.parentCategoryName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td> </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="subCategory in item.SubCategories">
            <td>{{subCategory.ChildCategoryName}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Rest you can alter according you. Hope it helps.